# How to call firebase/php-jwt class in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Currently I want to implement firebase/php-jwt into laravel 5

I've run the command `composer require firebase/php-jwt` under my laravel 5 project, and I get

```
"require": {
    ...
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^3.0"
},
```

in package.json

from config/app.php, I need inject this library, but don't know how to do.

---

#### Solution:

use [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) instead, 
and follow [JSON Web Token Tutorial: An Example in Laravel and AngularJS](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

Eventhough your front-end not using angular, it doesn't matter

Comment: This package doesn't seem to have any Service provider or Facade to register in config/app.php. [Here](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#example) is some limited documentation for the package. You can try [tymondesings/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) instead which has a much better documentation and support.

Comment: @Vikas ya, [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) works great with my RESTful API, maybe I will go to fork a firebase/php-jwt try to make a laravel version when I got time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing it via composer then

Add these two lines to your app.php

```
'J42\LaravelFirebase\LaravelFirebaseServiceProvider',
```

and

```
'Firebase'        => 'J42\LaravelFirebase\LaravelFirebaseFacade'
```

Also don't forget to add the credentials in your `config/database.php`

**Tip 1 :**

You shall with the basic requests like `Firebase::get('/my/path');`

Here's the good [resource](https://github.com/j42/laravel-firebase) to have a start with

**Tip 2 :** [Here](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) is the beautiful resource that you shall refer.

Comment: I'm not using firebase, I'm using php-jwt developed by firebase

Comment: Just just need to include the installation stuffs in your library ?

Comment: You want to include jwt `token` in your request or just include jwt library ?

Comment: jwt library class, I need call `JWT::encode ` function from my controller

Comment: should I change to use `auth-jwt`, it seems `php-jwt` is not customized for laravel

Comment: It was there.. Here's a good link that you shall refer [this](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) You shall make it done in your jquery instead of angularjs

Comment: Thank you, that article really helps

Comment: You're welcome.. If my answer helped you. You shall accept and upvote it.. +1 for your interest

Comment: actually your answer is not related to this question, you shall edit your answer anyway, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I wil do the same in few time. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's is resolved in version 5 as follow:
Assuming you have it from composer

```
    "require": {
        ...
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
    },
```

Then you just call this in your class:

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

...
protected function generateJwt(){
        if (config('jwt.secret')) {
            $now_seconds = time();
            $payload = array(
                    "iss" => ...,
                    "sub" => ...,
                    "aud" => ...,
                    "iat" => $now_seconds,
                    "exp" => $now_seconds + 60*60,  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
            );

            $this->jwt = JWT::encode($payload, config('jwt.secret'), "HS256");
        }

        Log::error("Missing JWT_SECRET in .env");
    }
```